# android how to download image form internet to local storage?

Tags: android, image, url, save, internal-storage

I want to download the image from URL internet to local storage and open the image from local storage to imageview ?

I saw these answers

[How to download and save an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Download images and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065071/download-images-and-save-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[downloading images with Picasso android disck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533228/downloading-images-with-picasso-android-disck?rq=1)

[Saving image from URL using Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799353/saving-image-from-url-using-picasso)

I know we can use **Picasso** and **Glide** and **Volley** and **Universal Image Loader** to do these job and there are other libraries also ...

**but** I can't implement the code of download image ! and can't find any new example of on the internet.
 I found some old example of Picasso library **old version**

can you give me the new code of download image from URL internet to local storage **or** any tutorial talk about this topic

Comment: And what is the problem with all of the links you shared? [The very first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549639/1790644) appears to be pretty comprehensive....

Comment: @Matt Clark   i can't implement the code of download image ! ... and can't find any new example of on internet ... i found some old example of Picasso library old virsion

Comment: Why can you not implement it? What could you possibly mean by you cant find any new examples? That post has the exact code to do the download...

Comment: @Matt Clark  like in picasso, this is old version     
  Picasso.with(MainActivity.class).load(myPhoto).into(picassoImageTarget(getApplicationContext(), "imageDir", "my_image.jpeg"));

Comment: And you still have not explain what you problem is, or why you can not implement these solutions.Maybe you should just go [read the docs for Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: @Matt Clark i can't find any example of download image from URL to local storage in docs of Picasso

Comment: You can try this code for downloading a URL of an image and save it in internal storage https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648729/7269831 Also, you can download files using DownloadManager like this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276803/7269831

Answer (score 1):

Try this one ...

Use this gradle : https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

and check this point : Downloading a file from server

Answer (score 0):

Use download Manager to download image from link(From Internet)

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ((Activity) context).getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle(fileName)
            .setDescription("file description")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(imgStoragePath, fileName)
            .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            //Download complete 

        }
    };
    context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```